# Ansible: run additional tasks for specific inventory

Tags: ansible

As per the "Best Practices" chapter in Ansible's documentation, I have separate inventory files for my development and production environments. While both environments get the same software stack installed, there are some differences: cron jobs are only installed on production hosts, symlinks to VirtualBox shared folders should only exist in the dev environment. I currently use a dev and a production role in addition to "common", and import their `main.yml` depending on the `inventory_hostname` variable.

This feels clumsy, because there's now a lot of folders and files for only a few additional tasks, and using `inventory_hostname` to distinguish between development and production environments violates the DRY principle because whether we're in dev or prod is now decided by the choice of inventory file and by the `inventory_hostname` variable. Is there a more elegant way to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html#alternative-directory-layout you can put a variable `env` in dev/group_vars/all.yml and prod/group_vars/all.yml.

If not you could add this to the end of the inventory file:

```
[all:vars]
env=foo
```